# Problem determining radius of convergence using root formula

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm struggling to find radius of convergence using the root formula. I've tried expanding the numbers but with no result. Would anyone like to help me out?

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^kk^{2k}}{k!}x^k$

Using root formula: $\sqrt[k]{|a_k|} \xrightarrow[k \to \infty]{} H$ where radius of convergence is $R ={\frac{1}{H}}$

I end up with

$\sqrt[k]{\frac{k^{2k}}{k!}}$ = ${\frac{k^{2}}{\sqrt[k]k!}}$

At this point i assumed there would be some kind of standard "limit" of the denominator but i didnt find any.

Comment: $\sqrt[k]{k!}\leq \sqrt[k]{k^k}=k$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Sorry, i forgot to write out the whole series, this is just the $a^k$ in the power series

Comment: Feng has given you the key to determining the limit of the roots of the factors. But from an intuitional standpoint, you can figure out what is going to happen just by examining the coefficients. For any infinite summation to converge, the summands must $\to 0$. But you can rewrite them as $(-1)^k\frac{k^k}{k!}(kx)^k$. $(-1)^k$ does not get larger or smaller as $k \to \infty$. But $\frac{k^k}{k!}$ consists of $k$ factors with $k$ in the numerator and numbers smaller than $k$ in the denominator, so it is bounded below by $1$. $(kx)^k \to \infty$ since $kx \to \infty$ if $x \ne 0$.